# Stopping a Tika server properly

Tags: java, apache-tika

In order to start a Tika server that can be accessed from hosts other that localhost we know that the way to go is (say I have version 1.7 and want to run on port 9998)

```
java -jar tika-server-1.7-SNAPSHOT.jar -host 0.0.0.0
```

My question is: Is there a proper way to properly stop this server with a command or is killing the process the only way?

Comment: [`SIGTERM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)#Examples) would be my first guess. Since this basically asks the process nicely to shut down if it wants to, I would consider that safe.

Comment: What's wrong with hitting control+c on the window where it's running?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Assume that you do not have access to that window (e.g. it is closed by another process / user).

Comment: Where do you try to run tika-server? on windows or linux?

Comment: Linux machine ( Ubuntu 12 )

Answer (score 2):

As of October 2019 there is no programmatic way to shut it down. [Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/tika/TikaJAXRS#TikaJAXRS-RunningtheTikaServer) notes:

> In the future, we may implement a gentler shutdown than we currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Apache tika 2.4.1 added stop() method to TikaServerCli so that it can be run with Apache Commons Daemon.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1570

https://downloads.apache.org/tika/2.4.1/CHANGES-2.4.1.txt