# Running a Tika server from eclipse to be accessed from hosts other than localhost

Tags: eclipse, apache-tika

I have the following question: I have imported in eclipse the tika-server subdirectory of the tika-trunk main repository and managed to import it to eclipse and I am able to start the "Apache Tika 1.7-SNAPSHOT server" on the machine I run eclipse (localhost). My problem is that I can only access Tika from this machine (localhost).

I know how to solve this problem when I start the Tika server from my command line (see post  [Stopping a Tika server properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633051/stopping-a-tika-server-properly) ), but I do not know how I can pass "-host 0.0.0.0" in order to instruct eclipse to do the same. I know that this might be solved through the "Run Configurations" eclipse menu but it is not intuitive to me how I can accomplish that. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, you need to open the Tika Server Cli class in eclipse. Then, do `Run As` followed by `Run Configuration`, as shown here:

[image: Run Configuration]

Now, in the configuration for the Tika Server CLI, in the program arguments box, enter the arguments you want to give to Tika, eg `--port 9876` as shown here

[image: Options]

Finally, hit Run and the Tika Server will start with the alternate port you've givne

Comment: Thank you Gagravarr, as usual all your Tika answers are perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution so far I found is to edit "TikaServerCli.java" and switch "public static final String DEFAULT_HOST" from "localhost" to "0.0.0.0". Then you can start the server in a way that can be accessed by everyone and not only by localhost.